# Sd card bigger than 2gb is not recognized in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: storage, sd-card, mass-storage

When I insert a card up to 2gb it is immediately seen by the system but if try it with bigger one it's not seen. I presume the issue is not due to the card reader itself as it reads all cards under windows 7 but due to linux driver.

I could see some people having similar issues but no solution.

Any help appreciated.

GParted doesnt see cards bigger than 2gb.

After insertion small card

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
[10169.384481] mmc0: new SD card at address a95c
[10169.384870] mmcblk0: mmc0:a95c SD016 14.0 MiB 
[10169.386715]  mmcblk0: p1
```

everything worked fine
then I removed the small one and put 8gb, waited for 2min

```
[10295.736422] mmc0: card a95c removed
[10362.448383] sdhci: Switching to 1.8V signalling voltage failed, retrying with S18R set to 0
[10372.480076] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10382.496146] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10392.512149] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10402.528145] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10402.529267] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[10402.748807] sdhci: Switching to 1.8V signalling voltage failed, retrying with S18R set to 0
[10412.768063] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10422.784051] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10432.800076] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10442.816067] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10442.817165] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[10443.040805] sdhci: Switching to 1.8V signalling voltage failed, retrying with S18R set to 0
[10453.056145] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10463.072139] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10473.088050] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10483.104046] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[10483.104107] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[10483.328960] sdhci: Switching to 1.8V signalling voltage failed, retrying with S18R set to 0
[10493.344144] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
0a:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02)
0a:01.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 02)
0a:01.3 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/xD Controller (rev 01)
```

**Same cards, same machine (same reader) only different OS(win7) work flawlessly.**

Some interesting reading I came across but is Chinese for me
    http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-mmc@vger.kernel.org/msg14598.html

and another bit
    http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.mmc/11973/match=sd+card+not+recognized

Comment: I have an 8GB card, and its recognized OK.  How is it formatted?

Comment: It is formated fat32.
And it works fine under windows 7 on the same machine.

Comment: It might help to specify the type of card reader you're using. It might be a problem with the driver of your specific card reader. I had a similar problem in the past with the card reader of my laptop which was solved by one of the recent kernel updates.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same with 8GB SD card. Problem is Ubuntu kernel is taking time to mount the card in its file system.

Solution: put the SD card in  SD card reader and leave it inserted for more than 1 hour.

Once kernel finish  mounting the SD, it will show up in left side bar.

Answer (score 0):

Run Disk utility to see if the card is detected, and if so try mounting it.
I have 4 GB SD cards with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SD cards are not recognized after an incorrect eject. Try this:

1. Unplug the SD card
2. Try restarting ubuntu
3. Once logged into your session, try plugging the SD card back into the SD card slot

Answer (score 0):

I was just experiencing this problem and I have decided it's likely the card reader (built into the ancient laptop) cannot handle SDHC cards. I believe the largest SD cards can be is 2GB, so obviously newer cards are more likely to be SDHC (SD High Capacity) cards.

Years back I had a Canon camera that could only take SD cards, and it became quite difficult to find new ones because just about all newer SD compatible cards are SDHC. Unfortunately I believe there's no firmware update that can make an old SD card reader recognize SDHC.

References:

[Ebay article from 2008 describing the "new" SDHC card format](http://www.ebay.com/gds/SD-memory-card-vs-newly-introduced-SDHC-standard-/10000000006764274/g.html)

[PC Magazine article stating older hardware cannot use newer card formats](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2388408,00.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of SD card:

- SD
- SDHC
- SDXC

The plain SD card can only store (at a maximum) 2GB. The SDHC can store max 32GB, while the SDXC and store up to 2TB of information.

The SD card reader is also important here. With a SD reader, you can only read SD cards. With a SDHC reader, you can read SD and SDHC. And so on...

It sounds like your laptop has a SD reader, so it can only read SD cards. It cannot read SDHC, SDXC, or any newer SD card.

In Windows' case, a driver may have been released to allow use of SDHC cards. As this driver is/was not yet ported to Ubuntu, you are out of luck. It may have been ported, though. Check for updates to the kernel. Also, just try to wait.

[(src)](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/capacity/)